# Trying to find a spec sheet on an old Toko active filter

Tags: active-filter

I'm trying to find the pin-out of an old low-pass filter I have. I must have lost my docs for it decades ago.  I've tried googling, but didn't turn up anything.

It's Toko part-number TK5429. I got it from DigiKey - probably in the 1990's. The writing on the little bag says "THB type Filter 14 KHz 7th order". The old DK part number is THB290.

The device has marked on it "B290 306I".

It has 5 in-line pins, a dot by pin 1.  Pins 1,2,3 are grouped together, and pins 4 and 5 are by themselves at the other end.

I know it's going to have +/- 15v, ground, and in and out, but I don't know which pin does what.

Does someone have an old Toko data-book?
Is there some non-destructive way to determine the pin functions?
Thanks!

Here's a snap-shot:
[image: image of Toko THB5429 filter]

Comment: I have a 1991 condensed Toko catalog in Japanese language, but only custom hybrids are shown. I guess you could ask Digikey for a scan of the page in  their catalog from the date on the bag. I also don't see the part number text in the online 1993 text-only (useless) Toko Integrated Circuit Databook on archive.org

Comment: Thank you for checking! I hadn't thought to look there. DK's catalogs were just part-numbers, description, and prices - no specs, really.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, just to include this clip from an [old Digikey](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/doc/DigiKey/SECTD.pdf) catalog:

[image]

No rhyme or reason to the pinouts really.

Comment: Wow! So close! Thank you! I'm quite wrong about the old DK catalogs not having part information. Thanks for finding that. Maybe a different one will turn up some day...